# Why divergence of Electric field is defined differenly as $\nabla \cdot \mathbf {E} ={\frac {4\pi \rho}{\varepsilon}}$ in f dependence of $\sigma$?

Tags: classical-electrodynamics

The derivation of Frequency dependence of conductivity in "Classical Electrodynamics - Greiner" uses following definition for Divergence of Eletric Field. 
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf {E} ={\frac {4\pi \rho}{\varepsilon}}$$

But the Maxwell's equations in **CGS** or **Gaussian** units doesn't have that ${\varepsilon}$ in denominator.

In Maxwell's Equation inside matter, Divergence of **E** is just $$\nabla \cdot \mathbf {E} ={4\pi \rho}$$

Please explain why this particular definition is used in this derivation?

Check line after Equation 16.26 on 2nd Page [Page No. 323] below.

[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]

Comment: Gauss's law in the presence of matter is $\nabla\cdot{\bf D}=4\pi\rho$, isn't it?  But note that Grenier's equation is true only if the medium is homogeneous and isotropic.  And one has to be careful about $\rho$.  Free charge, or all charge?

Comment: So the $\epsilon$ comes from $\nabla \cdot \mathbf {D} = {4\pi \rho}$ where ${D}=\epsilon{E}$, Right?
Means stepwise,
1) $\nabla \cdot \mathbf {D} = {4\pi \rho}$;
2) $\nabla \cdot \mathbf {\epsilon {E}} = {4\pi \rho}$; 
3) $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E}=\frac{4\pi \rho}{\varepsilon}$.

Comment: Yes, and step 3 works only if $\epsilon$ is homogeneous and isotropic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E}=\frac{4\pi \rho}{\varepsilon}$ Is a valid expresion to describe your system while you are assuming the charges of your system are free electrons. You don't have the possibility of induced charges.

Is important to know that the four Maxwell's equations are valid in all classic (with linear field response) electrodynamics systems we will find, the major problem is $how$ to use them in our problems. In fact, you have to note that the $\rho$ present in Gauss's law is $\rho = \rho_f +\rho_i$ where $\rho_f$ are the free charges and $\rho_i$ the induced ones.

The exact relations between $\mathbf{E}$, $\mathbf{D}$, $\rho$ and $\varepsilon$ are:
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{D} = 4\pi \rho_f $$
$$ \mathbf{D} = \varepsilon\mathbf{E} $$
In the general case $\varepsilon$ is a tensor, but for systems without polarization and for linear field responses, the direction of $\mathbf{D}$ and $\mathbf{E}$ are the same.

Comment: So the $\epsilon$ comes from $\nabla \cdot \mathbf {D} = {4\pi \rho}$ where ${D}=\epsilon{E}$, Right?
Means stepwise,
1) $\nabla \cdot \mathbf {D} = {4\pi \rho}$;
2) $\nabla \cdot \mathbf {\epsilon {E}} = {4\pi \rho}$; 
3) $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E}=\frac{4\pi \rho}{\varepsilon}$.

Comment: That's it, for this kind of systems.

Comment: Means for systems involving free charges? Thanks..

Comment: For homogeneous and isotropic systems with no induced charges and without polarization, i.e. involving only free charges.